# What is the most efficient way to render maths formulas in my android app?

Tags: android

I'm coding an android app (for offline use) and I need to display maths formulas and expressions on its views. What is the most efficient (easiest if possible) way to achieve this?

Comment: MathJax http://www.mathjax.org/ might do you. Its a javascript technology.

Comment: I had the same problem and wrote my own library. But that's a rather big task. If you can, go with mathjax or a similar approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way which comes to my mind is:

Rendering it with JavaScript using downloaded [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) in a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

For example, for such [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) on the input:

```
e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0
```

That will be the output:

[image: Euler's identity] 
<sub>([Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is to simply use a custom font in a TextView. When I was researching MathML I came across a font solution. I'll see if I can dig it out.

Font: https://github.com/fred-wang/android-latin-modern-math

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm going with MathJax method it's more efficient for my case.

Answer (score -1):

After an year, I found a library which could do this quite efficiently and have used this in current project. This is the link of that great work https://github.com/kexanie/MathView which you can easily include in your native code itself as another view component.This was way more faster than usual webview implementation of mathjax.